# "No such column Extent2.<fieldname>" Problems

Tags: c#, .net, data-modeling, edmx

I've inherited a large c# project and am running into issues updating the data model.
I have made my updates in the wysiwyg edmx data modelling editor (vs2010) and the updates seem fine. But it's hard to tell as when I run the program, immediately when it tries to access the database, I get this error:

"SQLite error no such column: Extent2.Country_ID"

Country_ID is a property of an existing entity (which I haven't modified), but I have no idea what "Extent2" is. I did a thorough text search through all related project files and it didn't come up once.

In the exception, the TargetSite reads:
{System.Data.Common.DbDataReader ExecuteStoreCommands(System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)}

Sadly, there isn't much more info; no error numbers or anything.
Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Extent2` is a table alias in the SQL generated by Entity Framework. It sounds like there's a bad relation or field mapping in your entity model somewhere that's causing the generated SQL commands to not match your actual database structure.

Comment: You are probably right, but sadly the wysiwyg edmx editor was so terrible that I just ended up not worrying about the relationship within the framework and added just the entity and manually handled the relationship

Answer (score 0):

If your application (which is using the Entity Framework on SQLite) is opening an old version of a database which has the table but not the column you can detect the missing column and add it programmatically as follows:-

```
    private EntityFrameworkEntities _modelInstance;

    protected override void Load()
    {
        bool retry = false;
        if (!TryLoad(out retry))
        {
            if (retry)
            {
                AddColumnToTableInDatabase();
                TryLoad(out retry);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool TryLoad(out bool retry)
    {
        bool success = false;
        retry = false;
        using (_modelInstance = new EntityFrameworkEntities())
        {
            _modelInstance.Connection.Open();

            var yourQuery = from entity in _modelInstance.Entitys
                               select entity;
            try
            {
                foreach (Entity entity in yourQuery)
                {
                    var vm = new EntityViewModel(entity, this);
                    base.Children.Add(vm);
                }
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                while (ex.InnerException != null)
                    ex = ex.InnerException;
                if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("no such column") && ex.Message.Split(new char[] { '.' })[1].Equals("Country_ID"))
                    retry = true;
                log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    private bool AddColumnToTableInDatabase()
    {
        bool success = false;
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(@"ALTER TABLE [Entity] ADD COLUMN [Country_ID] [text] NULL");
        using (_modelInstance = new EntityFrameworkEntities())
        {
            _modelInstance.Connection.Open();
            var connection = (_modelInstance.Connection as EntityConnection).StoreConnection as SQLiteConnection;
            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = sql.ToString();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```